# Privatize cloud firestore database using rules and authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing rules for cloud firestore for firebase, and I want to restrict the access to the database using users' auth id, but the rules are not behaving as I expect.

So, my database structure is like this:

/users/{userId}/groups/{groupId}

and I want only the users to only be able to access the documents with their own userId.

To achieve this, I write a rule like the following:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{userId=**} {
        allow read: if userId == request.auth.uid;
    }

  }
}
```

But with this, my user was not able to read their own "groups" from the database.

I am using javascript, and the code to retrieve "groups" is the following:

```
console.log("uid: ", uid)
db.collection("users/" + uid + "/groups")
  .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      console.log(doc.data())
    })
})
```

Now since cloud firestore does not have nice debugging tool like the realtime database, I did a little debugging on my own.

I have  a test user with uid of "5lS2NA21UgbabEw4AkyWyef9FH42", so I changed the rule like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{userId=**} {
        allow read: if "5lS2NA21UgbabEw4AkyWyef9FH42" == request.auth.uid;
    }

  }
}
```

With this, my test user was able to successfully retrieve "groups" data from his documents (of course all the other users can't, but).

Now I changed the rule to this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{userId=**} {
        allow read: if "5lS2NA21UgbabEw4AkyWyef9FH42" == userId;
    }

  }
}
```

And now I was not able to get any data from the database.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured this out. The problem was this {userId=**}

If you have the following rule

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{userId=**} {
        allow read: if userId == request.auth.uid;
    }

  }
}
```

and are trying to access users/5lS2NA21UgbabEw4AkyWyef9FH42/groups, the "userId" variable does not evaluate to be 5lS2NA21UgbabEw4AkyWyef9FH42 (I don't know what it would be, but I would guess "5lS2NA21UgbabEw4AkyWyef9FH42/groups"). So if you want to privatize documents, you have to specify every document in the rule like the following.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{userId} {
        match /groups/{groupId} {
           allow read: if userId == request.auth.uid;
        }
        match /events/{eventId} {
           allow read: if userId == request.auth.uid;
        }
    }

  }
}
```